# How to test if an .app (application directory) exists in bash on OSX?

Tags: macos, bash

I want to test if a file or directory exist thru a bash script :

```
    if [ -f "$file" -o -d "$file" ]; then
        # Do things
    fi
```

but this test won't work on an application file (.app), I couldn't find an answer on the test man page and was thinking that a .app was considered as a folder on osx.

Comment: use `-e` instead. Also all the flags are in the bash man page.

Comment: `-d` should work. What is the value of `file`?

Comment: You can just use -e to check if it's a file OR directory. `if [ -e "$file" ];` then

Comment: the -e works perfect, sorry for this terrible question, I wrotted it from the beggining and it worked with -d, won't ask another thing without further tests. Thanks !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if a directory exists :

```
if [ -d "$<app name>.app" ]; then
  # Control will enter here if $<app name>.app exists.
fi
```

Check if a directory doesn't exist:

```
if [ ! -d "$<app name>.app" ]; then
  # Control will enter here if $<app name>.app doesn't exist.
fi
```

Comment: I don't want to have to check for a directory, I want to know if the application actually exists in Mac OS.

Comment: An app is a directory structure, so this is a valid way of testing if the app exists @jamescampbell

Comment: Yes a blunt, poor way to do it in my opinion that costs extra CPU cycles. Happily proved wrong if you can point to this approach being faster than others. @StefanS

Comment: @james-see, checking if a directory exists is pretty fast, there might not be a faster way to do this check. Yes, it involves filesystem access, but applications exist in the filesystem. I made a simple script that does this check 100000 times, and the entire script runs in about 370 ms on average. The other answer's `open -Ra ...` test runs only about 55 times in the same amount of time. You say this is "blunt and poor", I say it's simple, beautiful, and very Unix-like.

Comment: John Sidle’s answer is much cleaner and performant and what I used. Sorry for my aggressive tone in my comment, I agree this solution is simple and works well.

Answer (score 3):

**Simple Bash command-line test that an Os X application exists**

```
if open -Ra "$<app name>" ; then
  # Control will enter here if $<app name>.app exists.
else
  # Control will enter here if $<app name>.app doesn't exist.
fi
```

**Example: is the application `TeXShop` installed?**

```
if open -Ra "TeXShop" ; then
  echo "VERIFIED: 'TeXShop' is installed"
else
  echo "ERROR: 'TeXShop' is not installed"
fi
```

**Remarks**

The test is fast --- about 20 msec on my MacBook Pro -- and (apparently) has no Finder side-effects. The test works (apparently) for any Os X app that responds appropriately to:

```
open -a "${<app name>}" "${<file name}"
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I used the example in my nice-bash github repo to check for system default browsers and auto open a url, this particular one is after other checks have failed it realizes that it is not windows or linux so must be Mac OS and checks and opens Safari.